# Groovy example for printing from web page

Tags: printing, web, groovy

I need to create a web page where one of the icons will be the printer icon, and it should print to the printer attached to the device the browser is running on. I have not been able to see any groovy/grails code example that does this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript to perform this task.

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">
 <IMG SRC="printer.gif">
</A>
```

Comment: Thank you, you made it easy :)